# How to add a scrollbar to tcl frame

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am creating a list of radiobuttons on a frame, the list eventually becomes huge and its difficult for user to select items.
Is there anyway i can add a scrollbar to this frame?
I tried adding listbox, but no help.

This is my code.

```
frame .top.d.b -width 100 -height 20 -borderwidth 2 -relief raised
label .top.d.b.l1 -font fontTEMP_varwidth -text "Comparision Libraries" -anchor center -padx 2 -pady 4
set whu .top.d.b
grid .top.d.b -row 7 -column 2 -sticky nsew
grid .top.d.b.l1 -row 1 -column 2
set w 0
foreach elem $mylist {
radiobutton .top.d.b.$w -text $elem -command [list selectlib $elem $w] -value $elem.abc -padx 2 -pady 2
grid .top.d.b.$w -row $a -column $r -sticky w
incr a
incr w
}
} else {
puts "STD_CELLS_LIBPATH not found\n"
}
}
```

Comment: In this case a [listbox](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/listbox.htm) is much useful than radiobuttons.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a canvas combined with scrollbars, than you put your widgets on the canvas. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

ttk::frame .frAlles

# create canvas with scrollbars
canvas .frAlles.c -width 400 -height 200 -xscrollcommand ".frAlles.xscroll set" -yscrollcommand ".frAlles.yscroll set"
ttk::scrollbar .frAlles.xscroll -orient horizontal -command ".frAlles.c xview"
ttk::scrollbar .frAlles.yscroll -command ".frAlles.c yview"
pack .frAlles.xscroll -side bottom -fill x
pack .frAlles.yscroll -side right -fill y
pack .frAlles.c -expand yes -fill both -side top

# create frame with widgets
ttk::frame .frAlles.c.frWidgets -borderwidth 1 -relief solid -width 340 -height 700

for {set i 0} {$i <=20} {incr i} {
  ttk::label .frAlles.c.frWidgets.lb$i -text "Label $i:"
  ttk::entry .frAlles.c.frWidgets.en$i
  ttk::button .frAlles.c.frWidgets.bt$i -text "Button $i" -command exit
  grid .frAlles.c.frWidgets.lb$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 0
  grid .frAlles.c.frWidgets.en$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 1
  grid .frAlles.c.frWidgets.bt$i -padx 2 -pady 2 -row $i -column 2 
}

# create frame with buttons
ttk::frame .frAlles.c.frButtons -borderwidth 1 -relief solid -width 340 -height 40
ttk::button .frAlles.c.frButtons.btOK -text "OK" -command exit
ttk::button .frAlles.c.frButtons.btAbbruch -text "Abbruch" -command exit
pack .frAlles.c.frButtons.btOK -padx 2 -pady 2 -side left
pack .frAlles.c.frButtons.btAbbruch -padx 2 -pady 2 -side left

# place widgets and buttons
.frAlles.c create window 0 0 -anchor nw -window .frAlles.c.frWidgets 
.frAlles.c create window 200 650 -anchor c -window .frAlles.c.frButtons 

# determine the scrollregion
.frAlles.c configure -scrollregion [.frAlles.c bbox all]

# show the canvas
pack .frAlles -expand yes -fill both -side top
```

Answer (score 2):

Only widgets that implement Tk's scrolling protocol can be associated with a scrollbar; frames are not such a widget.

However, you can put your frame inside a canvas (via the “widget” canvas item type) and canvases *are* scrollable provided you tell the canvas what the scroll region is. You'll want to make sure that the frame and its contents are children of the canvas in order for the clipping of them to work right.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Only widgets that have scrollcommand options (-xscrollcommand, -yscrollcommand) and xview / yview widget commands can be scrolled.

Comment: Okay, Right but then can size of radiobutton's can be reduced to accommodate in same size frame ? Is there any option for radiobutton size ?

Comment: @DanishSheikh: have you looked in the documentation? Yes, there is, but don't do that. Try using a listbox instead, like Mario suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is late but colud help others.
You could think of using Bwidgets  it has many widgets like scrolled windows, frames. https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/BWidget